# Dynamics AX 2012 Subquery in a View

Tags: view, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

AX allows you to enter basic SQL into View ranges.  For example, in an AOT view's range, for the match value, you could enter (StatRepInterval.Name == 'Weekly').  This works nicely.

However, I need to do a more advanced lookup on a View, using a subquery.  Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

This is what I would like to use, but I receive an error: "Query extended range failure: Syntax error near 34."

(StatRepInterval.Name == (SELECT FIRSTONLY StatRepInterval.Name FROM StatRepInterval WHERE StatRepInterval.PrintDirection == 1 ORDER BY StatRepInterval.Name DESC))

I've tried a lot of different variants of the subquery, from straight T-SQL to X++ SQL, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.  It isn't pretty, and I'm going to leave the question unanswered for a bit, should someone else have a more graceful solution.

1. Create a source View that contains all fields I wish to return, plus calculated fields that contain my subquery results.
2. Create a second View that uses the first as a data source, and applies all the necessary ranges.

Works pretty nicely.

Probably inefficient if there were large tables of data, but this is in a relatively small section of AX.

Answer (score 1):

Sub-queries are not supported in query expressions.

This may be solved by using additional datasources with inner or outer joins as you observed.

See [the spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/aa893981.aspx) and [Axaptapedida](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges) on query expressions.